# Finding symmetries of a Lagrangian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry

Starting from the following Lagrangian,
$$
L=\frac{1}{2} (m\dot{x}^{2}-kx^{2}) e^{(b/m)t}
$$
how can you find the most general spacetime transformation that leaves the Lagrangian invariant (up to total derivatives)? i.e., find  $\chi(x,t)$ and $\tau(x,t)$ such that
$$
t\rightarrow t'= t +\epsilon \cdot \tau(x,t)  \hspace{5mm} (\epsilon \ll1)
$$
$$
x\rightarrow x'= x+\epsilon \cdot \chi(x,t)  \hspace{5mm} (\epsilon \ll1)
$$
leaves the Lagrangian invarant.

---

What I have done is:

starting with
$$
t\rightarrow t'= t +\epsilon \cdot \tau(x,t)=t+\delta t  \hspace{5mm} (\epsilon \ll1)
$$
$$
x\rightarrow x'= x+\epsilon \cdot \chi(x,t)=x+\delta x  \hspace{5mm} (\epsilon \ll1)
$$
then
$$
\dot{x'}=\dot{x}+\epsilon \dot{\chi}
$$

So

$$
L(x',\dot{x}',t)=\frac{1}{2} (m\dot{x}'^{2}-kx'^{2}) e^{(b/m)t'}
$$

Using
$$
\dot{x}'^{2}=\dot{x}^{2}+2\dot{x}\epsilon\dot{\chi}
$$
$$
x'^{2}=x^{2}+2x\epsilon\chi
$$
because I want first order expansions only (Noether's approximation).

So finally I can put all in $L(x',\dot{x}',t)$ and apply symmetry test 
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{i}}\delta q_{i}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\delta \dot{q}_{i}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\delta t=0 \hspace{5mm} (1)
$$

where I have put that $F=0$.

applying (1) over $L(x',\dot{x}',t)$ I can obtain 3 ODEs which result is:

$$
\tau(x,t)=\frac{-t}{\epsilon}
$$
$$
\chi(x,t)=\frac{-x}{\epsilon}
$$

is it right?

Comment: See, for example, [Symmetries and conservation laws of the damped
harmonic oscillator](http://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/pram/070/04/0657-0667)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform thank you but I need to use what is called like ''symmetry test'': $\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_{i}}\delta q_{i}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_{i}}\delta \dot{q}_{i}+\frac{\partial L}{\partial t}\delta t=0$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform could you explain me how can I rewrite L' (in terms of $t'$, $q'$) and which are the terms that I can eliminate?
Using symmetry test I might find 3 ODEs. Other problem is to integrate, because $\tau$ and $\chi$ depend on two variables.

Comment: Leave *t* alone for a moment. @AccidentalFourierTransform 's paper by Chaudhuri et al tells you how to transform to the plain oscillator, *x*  ↦ *z* . Are you familiar with the plain oscillator [fractional fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_Fourier_transform) symmetry discovered by Condon?

Comment: @CosmasZachos no... The instructions from the exercise are: a)Compute the equation of motion b)In order to determine a rst integral of Emden's equation, apply Noether's method, that is, search for an uniparametric family of transformations; that leaves the Lagrangian invariant. Apply the symmetry test (with F = 0) to determine the dierential equations. c)Integrate the dierential equations obtained.  ||  I am very worried because I have been all the morning and I can't get the result

Comment: Did you start by scaling *t* up and *x* and the velocity down, so *τ* =1, *χ=-xb/(2m)*  and its time derivative in consequence?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I have uploaded the top question with the details of my solution. Could you explain me where I am wrong, why and how can I find the correct way to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: Your increment of the velocity is definitely wrong, to lowest order in *ε*. You have 2 terms, the first one of which should simply not be there.

Comment: @CosmasZachos this is wrong?? $\dot{x'}=\dot{x}+\epsilon \chi'(x,t)\dot{x}+\epsilon \dot{\chi}$

Comment: @CosmasZachos or this one? $\dot{x}'^{2}=\dot{x}^{2}+2\dot{x}\epsilon(\chi'\dot{x}+\dot{\chi})$

Comment: The correct transform is $\dot{x'}=\dot{x} +\epsilon \dot{\chi}$ to this order in *ε*.  Last message.